# How can I parse XML in PowerShell when each property has a unique name?

Tags: xml, powershell, oop, parsing, powershell-2.0

I have an xml file like so:

```
<employees>   
    <employee>
        <name>Johnny Rocket</name>
        <age>40</age>
        <somethingelse>Whatever</somethingelse>
        <another>Whatever Again</another>
        ##.... lots more ....##
    </employee>
    <employee>
        ##......
    </employee>

</employees>
```

I want to create a custom PowerShell object for each "employee" you see. However, I don't want to have to explicitly state the properties (Name, Age, SomethingElse, Whatever), because in reality there are tens of them. I want to have each property of my object to be named what's in the brackets.

I would also want the solution to work if what's in the brackets is two words. In the following example, I would want the object's member to be named "Food" with value "Pasta":

`<Food Type="Italian">Pasta</Food>`)

Is there a solution that can create a custom object whose member names are defined by what is in the brackets, which works with PowerShell 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can enumerate all child nodes of a given XML node with the `ChildNodes` property:

```
$EmployeesXml = [xml](Get-Content .\employees.xml)

# Locate all <employee> nodes, iterate over them
foreach($EmployeeNode in $EmployeesXml.SelectNodes('//employees/employee')){
    # Create hashtable to hold employee data
    $EmployeeData = @{}
    # Iterate over each child node under <employee>
    $EmployeeNode.ChildNodes |ForEach-Object {
        # Populate employee data based on the node name
        $EmployeeData[$_.Name] = $_.InnerText
    }

    # Create object from collected data
    New-Object psobject -Property $EmployeeData
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want, but I want a distinct object for each Employee, rather than one object containing every employee. Also, I would like each property (e.g. Name, Age) to explicitly be a member of the object (as in `-AddMember NoteProperty`), rather than a hash table. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning The sample above *does* create an object per employee node. The `New-Object psobject -Property $EmployeeData` creates an object with properties based on the data in the `$EmployeeData` hashtable

Comment: You're a wizard, Mathias! Thank you.